# How to show a count down/up in react

Tags: reactjs

This is my code at the moment and I am trying to use react as a counter.

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React',
      countstart : 1 ,
      countend : 20,
    };
  }

  counter = () => {
    if(this.state.countstart < this.state.countend) {
      this.setState({countstart : this.state.countstart + 1})
    }
  }


componentDidUpdate() {
  setTimeout(()=>
  {
  this.counter()
  }
   , 1000)
}

  render() {
    this.counter()
    return (
      <div>
        <Hello name={this.state.name} />
        <p>
          {this.state.countstart}
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I want the number to count from 1 to 20 with the specified timeout milliseconds, so that it goes from 1 then 2 and so on, how am I able to achieve that by using the above code ?

Comment: Is there issues with the code above that you can tell us about to help point out what's going on?

Comment: You may find it more useful to learn React by following the docs, which have [an example that's almost identical to your question](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html). StackOverflow can really only help you solve problems that are more specific in nature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`. Also, you can just kick off the counter in `componentDidMount`.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React',
      countstart : 1 ,
      countend : 20,
    };
    this.counter = this.counter.bind(this);
    this.count = this.count.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.count();
  }

  counter = () => {
    if(this.state.countstart < this.state.countend) {
      this.setState({countstart : this.state.countstart + 1})
    }
  }


  count() {
    setInterval(()=>
    {
    this.counter()
    }
     , 1000)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Hello name={this.state.name} />
        <p>
          {this.state.countstart}
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, instead of `setTimeout`, you need to use `setInterval` to run a method at a specified interval.

2ndly, you need to store the `intervalID` and make sure to stop it before the component unmounts in `componentWillUnmount`.

```js
class App extends Component {

    intervalID = 0;

    componentDidUpdate() {
        this.intervalID = setInterval(()=>
        {
        this.counter()
        }
        , 1000)
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.intervalID);
    }

    // rest of code redacted... for brevity

}
```

*Here is a shameless plug on [how to cancel the setInterval](https://dev.to/dance2die/canceling-interval-in-react-52b5).*